# Total sum value inputs ngFor / Reactive Form

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I achieve a total sum of two values that are in an input field and store that result in another input field?

Something like this:
[image]

In other words, these two values `value1` and `value2` already have them with *ngFor but I can not do the addition and also when any of the values change, the result is modified.

component.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-md-3">
  <mat-label>Precio regular</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="number" formControlName="precioRegular" value="{{paquete.precio}}" (change)="updateTotal(paquete.precio)">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-md-3">
  <mat-label>Descuento</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="number" formControlName="descuento" value="{{paquete.descuento}}" (change)="updateTotal(paquete.descuento)">
  </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-md-3">
  <mat-label>Precio Final</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="precioFinal" [value]="total">
</mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
  total: number;

  this.forma = this.fb.group({
    precioRegular: [  ],
    descuento: [  ],
    precioFinal: [ ],
  });


 updateTotal(item) {
    if (item) {
      this.total += item.value;
    } else {
      this.total -= item.value;
    }
    // console.log(this.total);
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like an ideal use-case for Reactive Forms. You should use template-driven forms instead.

Comment: input form elements are used to gather... inputs from the user. Not to store output of a calculation. Why store the output in an input?

Comment: It is because the new data that the user enters, will be stored later in a database

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to changes of reactive form and perform some action with form value.

For example:

```
this.forma.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
 const sum = calculateSum(value);
 this.forma.get('precioFinal').setValue(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said, this isn't the ideal use case for using Reactive Forms. You'd generally use Reactive Forms when you have a Data Model in place and you want to build a form around it, or you want to get the value of the form according to that data model.

In the current scenario, you would be better off, just by using `[(ngModel)]`.

Here, give this a try:

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-md-3">
    <mat-label>Precio regular</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="model.precioRegular">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-md-3">
    <mat-label>Descuento</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="model.descuento">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-md-3">
    <mat-label>Precio Final</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="number" [value]="model.precioRegular + model.descuento">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And in your template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  model = {
    precioRegular: 0,
    descuento: 0,
  };
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-model-with-angular-material?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Also add `readonly` in `Precio Final` input so that total can't be manipulated. :D

Comment: Updated the StackBlitz. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to any change from the form and add the values together.

`this.forma.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
 const sum = value.precioRegular + valuee.descuento;
 this.forma.get('precioFinal').setValue(sum);
});`